# Why is selecting an option within <select> using querySelector.value causing the option to disappear?

Tags: reactjs

I have a  element in my render function as follows:-

```
<select 
 onChange={this.toggleModalclose.bind(this)} 
 className="modalsearchcity" 
 placeholder="Select City"
>
  <option  style={{color: '#58caeb'}} >--SELECT A CITY--</option>                    
  {this.state.cities.map((cat) => (
     <option  style={{color: '#58caeb'}} value={cat}>{cat}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

I am trying to select a default city using this in componentDidUpdate:-

```
document.querySelector(".searchCity").value=this.state.selectedcity;
```

But for some reasons upon component load I am getting that place empty as in nothing shows up at all.I also used console log to check this state value:-
`console.log(this.state.selectedcity)` and I can see that the state contains the proper value. The   box is still visible and options also show up when the select is clicked but the selected option is not shown.Instead of the selected option I get it empty. Why is it so .How to fix it.

Comment: Can you try adding the "select a default city" in `componentDidMount`? Don't remove the code from `componentDidUpdate`; but, have it in both methods. If works, we can make it look better later.

Comment: cant do that ...the <select>gets lodaed after update only

Comment: You mean the `select` is not rendered on the first render?

Comment: yea its not rendered on the first render

Comment: I think we will need to see more of your render method then.